# Custom Page in SilverStripe Admin

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to create a fully custom Page in SilverStripe's (v3.4) Admin.

It should just display a Form (consisting of an UploadField and a FormAction to submit the File) which submits to a custom action.

So far this is my Code.

```
class ImporterAdmin extends LeftAndMain {

private static $url_segment = 'importer';
private static $url_rule = '/$Action';
private static $menu_title = 'Produkt Import';
private static $menu_icon = 'mysite/icons/pimport-icon.png';
private static $allowed_actions = array(
    "run_import" => true
);

public function init() {
    parent::init();
    // Gather required client side resources
    Requirements::javascript(CMS_DIR . '/javascript/CMSMain.EditForm.js');
}


public function index($req){

    return $this->renderWith("ImporterAdmin_Content");
}


public function getResponseNegotiator() {
    // Get the reponse negotiator
    $negotiator = parent::getResponseNegotiator();
    $controller = $this;
    // Set the callback template
    $negotiator->setCallback('CurrentForm', function() use(&$controller) {
        return $controller->renderWith('ImporterAdmin_Content');
    });

    return $negotiator;
}
public function getImportForm($id = null, $fields = null) {
    $fields = new FieldList(
        UploadField::create("XMLFile", "XML File")
    );
    // Get the form actions
    $actions = new FieldList(
        FormAction::create('run_import', _t('CMSMain.SAVE', 'Save'))->addExtraClass('ss-ui-action-constructive')->setAttribute('data-icon', 'accept')
    );

    // Create the form
    $form = CMSForm::create($this, 'ImportForm', $fields, $actions)->setHTMLID('Form_ImportForm');

    // Set the response action, mostly for returning the correst template
    $form->setResponseNegotiator($this->getResponseNegotiator());

    // Add required classes to the form
    $form->addExtraClass('cms-content center cms-edit-form');

    // Convert buttons to button tags (apprently required for jQuery styling)
    $actions = $actions->dataFields();
    if($actions) {
        foreach($actions as $action) {
            $action->setUseButtonTag(true); 
        }
    }
    return $form;
}
/**
 * Save the settings
 * @param  array $data The form data
 * @param  CMSForm $form The form object
 * @return SS_HTTPResponse The SilverStripe viewresponse
 */
public function run_import($data, $form) {
    print_r($data, $form);
}
```

But it displays nothing...

The ImportForm.ss file just contains the Variable $ImportForm

Comment: `ModelAdmin` already has import functionality. Dependin on what you need I'd have a look at that first. See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.0/reference/modeladmin/

Comment: Yes but only for csv files

Comment: Shouldn't your template be named `ImporterAdmin_Content.ss` instead of `ImportForm.ss`?